# conditional validation: if file upload, then check minimum size

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want a validation in my organisations model that runs only, when an image file is selected for upload.

app/models/organisation.rb

```
class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, :url, :street, :city, :zipcode, presence: true

  validate :validate_minimum_image_size, if: # file is selected for upload 


  def validate_minimum_image_size
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(picture.path)
    unless image[:width] > 300 && image[:height] > 300
      errors.add :image, "should be 300px minimum!" 
    end
  end

end
```

Is there a way to check image size when the image file is selected to upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide your own custom method sth like :

```
   validate :validate_minimum_image_size, if: :file_present?

   def file_present?
     picture ? true : false
   end
```